# What is minimal height of Cocoa's progressbar?

Tags: macos, cocoa

In **Lazarus** wrapper for **Cocoa** controls, we have limitation: progressbar which height is less than 16 pixels, looks clipped from top and bottom. (Ie, top/bottom borders hide.) I tested it on old MacOS 10.8.

Is this the limit of Cocoa itself, or Cocoa allows small progressbar height (5..16 pixels), so it's Lazarus wrapper limit?

Comment: I don't recall the progress bar appearance in 10.8, but there are two sizes of progress bar controls: regular and small. Programmatically, you can set the `controlSize` property to `NSControlSizeSmall`. It will still be a fixed size, but maybe smaller than 16 points in height. In macOS 10.12, both sizes of progress bar are (visually) 12 points in height.

Comment: @KenThomases Hm, what is pixel height of a bar, for which we must use "small" size? 16 pixels, 19, other?

Comment: In IB the regular height is 18, the small height is 12. Mini is not available in IB.

Comment: 18 and 12 are the frame (and layout) heights. However, the visual height on 10.12 is 6 for both. (I wrote 12 earlier, but I was fooled by Retina mode.) So, on this version of the OS, you could probably set such a small height and not visually clip it, depending on how exactly the clipping rectangle is positioned relative to the control's frame. But that would be different for different versions of the OS, like what you're seeing on 10.8. And there's currently no way to find out the visual size.